# installing numpy with python 3.4

Tags: python, numpy

I have alias defined in my `.zshrc` as `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.4`. Problem is when I try to install `numpy(v1.8.1)` it get installed with `python2.7`. I would like to install it with `python3.4`

Any help appreciated. I am using RHEL distro.

Installation instructions:

Ran the following in the source directory of the extracted tar downloaded from website.

`python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu`

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you are trying to perform a *system install*. This means that, at some point after building the sources as you described, you are probably running a command such as:

```
$sudo python setup.py install
```

<sup>This is an assumption, but a good one given what you explained.</sup>

**Note**: if you aren't doing this then you are simply building the library but *not installing it properly*, so what you see is that `numpy` is *already installed* for python2.7 and you are *not* installing it for python3.4 at all.

Now the problem here is that you *think* that `sudo python` should use `python3.4` but *this is not the case*. Since the alias is defined only for your user it will *not* be used when running commands with `sudo`. So the default `python` is executed, which is probably python2.7:

```
$alias python=python3.4
$python
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$sudo python
[sudo] password for username: 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

(note that `python` and `sudo python` launch two different interpreters)

To fix this simply call the `python3.4` executable explicitly:

```
$sudo python3.4 setup.py install
```

You can also install `numpy` only for the current user using the `--user` option:

```
$python3.4 setup.py install --user
```

In this case the alias works so in your system it's the same as:

```
$python setup.py install --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `easy_install`. Try this instead:

```
# pip install numpy
```

`python 3.4` is bundled with `pip`  by default.

Comment: I did not use easy_install. I compiled from source.

Comment: can you try `pip`? or you absolutely need to compile numpy from sources?

Comment: "pip is bundled with python 3.4 by default" erm, not at all. It's the other way round: python3.4 always ships with `pip` but `pip` was being shipped independently for many other python versions for a long time so in a system with multiple python versions it's not at all said that `pip` will install things for python3.4 by default.

Comment: @Bakuriu: right. I was supposed to write `python 3.4` is bundled with `pip` by default. going to edit that now. thanks!